# SVN: how to find when the file is added into repository

Tags: svn

How can we efficiently use svn to find when a file or a directory is introduced into our trunk ?
I tried to find that through keyword in svn log. However not working, maybe our team svn log is not that detail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easiest (but not necessarily most effective) solution is to use `svn log`, but limit it only to file, that you're interested in:

```
svn log --limit 1 -r0:HEAD ^/trunk/README
```

But this might not be info, that you're interested in (e.g. what if README file was introduced on branch and you want to learn, when it was merged into trunk?). In such case, you might want to additionally pass `--stop-on-copy`.

This is not really effective, because you're asking SVN to iterate through history and you can't easily download project history to your local working copy. If you need to find this info often and effectively, consider using `git-svn` to import your project to git repo. Then you'll be able to use something akin to `git log README | tail` and it will work in fraction of a second.